# How do I select Debugging on my Phone (Visual Studio)

Tags: xamarin

The only choices I have for "Emulator" is Pixel Pie. My phone is a Samsung A51. How do I debug on the phone? (Note: I have debugged a related app on my phone for about a year.)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/debugging/debug-on-device?tabs=windows

Comment: First enable devloper option >> turn on usb debugging.
Then run your project

Comment: It is on. For a long time. I have been debugging an app on it. But now my only choices are Pixel Pie.

Comment: My debug targets are now limited to Pixel 3. I cannot debug on the phone.

Comment: Reboot your phone and PC.  Can adb see your phone?